# Python 2.7 - Delete all the __init__.py and __init__.pyc files recursively

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, recursion, removeall

I'm developing a python command-line tool, and it should delete the `__init__.*` files in the entire project tree. I tried this:

```
subprocess.call(['find', './<directory>', -name, '"__init__.*"', '-delete'])
```

where  actually has the path...

Any ideas?

**NOTE:** This works using the terminal. When it comes to do it in python, however; it will not delete anything (the script continues though, it doesn't throw any errors).

Comment: I hope you know that `__init__.py` files are important, even when empty, as they declare packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the glob module to remove the files under a given subdirectory:

```
import glob, os
init_files = glob.glob('./directory/__init__.*')
for f in init_files: os.remove(f)
```

To go through subdirectories recursively you could use the `os.walk` function:

```
import os, fnmatch
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./directory'):
    for f in fnmatch.filter(files, '__init__.*'):
        os.remove(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

The bash command you want to execute is this:

```
find ./<directory> -name "__init__.py*" -exec  rm -rf {} \;
```

Before you jump into it, run the following to print which files will actually be removed:

```
subprocess.check_output(['find', './<directory>','-name', '__init__.py*', '-exec', 'echo', '{}', ';']).split('\n')
```

Then, if that looks good, run this:

```
subprocess.check_output(['find', './<directory>','-name', '__init__.py*', '-exec', 'rm', '{}', ';'])
```